# Rails - Can I Show Different Partials in a View After an Error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails 5 app that has a view that shows different forms based on params.  The correct form is shown when the view first shows

However, when there's an error, it always shows the same partial.

diary_controller

```
def edit
  @view = params[:view]
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @diary.update(diary_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @diary, notice: 'Diary was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @diary }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @diary.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

edit.html.erb

```
<% if @view == 'close' %>
  <%= render 'close_fields'%>
<% elsif @view == 'new'%>
  <%= render 'new_fields' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'all_fields' %>
<% end %>
```

Currently, it always shows the `'all_fields'` partial when there's an error.

Is it possible to show the partial originally shown while retaining the data the user entered in the fields, along with the error messages (currently shown under the text field because I use simple_form)?

------------UPDATE------------

When I add `puts params[:view]` in `:edit`, it returns `close` in the console.

When I add `puts params[:view]` in `:update`, it returns nothing in the console.  I also tried putting `@view = "close"` in update.  When I did this, the correct view was shown after an error.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"f7JoOucLkUlOyt31NW9HaJIWyXKVSu7q91kspfZYjgdF3hJneRKapnCPtgJn+R5NOC5nDhNvkB8PzzHNs9aLkg==", "diary"=>{"last_date"=>"", "notes"=>"hi, hi!", "update_type"=>"close", "view"=>"close"}, "reason_list_select2"=>"going on vacation", "season_reason_list_select2"=>"", "temp_reason_list_select2"=>"", "area"=>[{"id"=>"4", "action"=>"Not Applicable"}], "commit"=>"Close Diary", "id"=>"27"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `update` action, you never set `@view` and so it is always `nil` in which case your `if... elsif... else` statement always resolves to `<%= render 'all_fields' %>`.

If you want your `if` statement in `edit.html.erb` to resolve to something other than `else`, then set your `@view` variable in your `update` action.

Based on the update to your question, the problem is now that `:view` is nested inside `:diary`:

```
"diary"=>{"last_date"=>"", "notes"=>"hi, hi!", "update_type"=>"close", "view"=>"close"}
```

So, you need to do `@view = params[:diary][:view]` instead of `@view = params[:view]`.

Comment: Thanks!  I added `<%= f.hidden_field :view, :value => @view %>` to my form and added `@view = @diary.view` to the `update` action, but it still renders all fields.  I was wondering if I need to change `format.html { render :edit }`?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your console output  when you're hitting the `edit` action to your question? In particular, your `params` values?

Comment: Yes, in edit when I have, `puts params[:view]`, then close shows in the console (no parenthesis around close).  Thanks!

Comment: And update? (Please add to your question, don't put in comments.)

Comment: You should really put your actual params from your console in your question, not your `puts params[:view]` output. Either your `hidden_field` is malformed, or your `view` value is nested. But, since you don't show either your `html` or your `params`, it's hard to say.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant with the parameters.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185465/discussion-between-jvillian-and-yellowreign).

Answer (score 0):

In your diary_controller

```
before_action :load_view, only: [:edit, :update]

# Your action methods here

private

def load_view
  @view = params[:view]
end
```

And make sure in all your forms (close_fields, new_fields, all_fields), you have a hidden filed named `view` which value is set to @view.

Comment: I added `<%= f.hidden_field :view, :value => @view %>` to my form and added `@view = @diary.view` to the update action, but it still renders all fields.

Comment: @yellowreign Can you use `byebug` and see what is the value it's getting when rendering error form

Answer (score 0):

Once try like this in your
edit.html.erb

```
<% if @view.to_s == 'close' %>
 <%= render :partial => 'close_fields'%>
<% elsif @view.to_s == 'new'%>
 <%= render :partial => 'new_fields' %>
<% else %>
 <%= render :partial =>'all_fields' %>
<% end %>
```

Note :your partial  file name should have an underscore like this: _all_fields.html.erb